# Distribution of frequency count from one category to another in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
emp.data <- data.frame(
  emp_id = c(1:32), 
  dealer_code = c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A3","A8","A4","A6","A6","A7","A1","A8","A9","A1","A2","A7","A8","A1","A1","A2","A2","A5","A4","A4","A10","A10","A10","A10","A3","A3","A11"),
  region = c("UK","US","OZ","IN","US","OZ","UK","IN","PAK","PAK","IN","UK","UK","OZ","UK","US","IN","UK","UK","UK","US","US","US","IN","IN","PAK","PAK","PAK","PAK","OZ","OZ","UK"))
```

And If i take a freq table

```
df <- emp.data %>%
  group_by(dealer_code) %>%
  count()
```

I want to distribute those dealer codes whose count is greater than 3 to those whose count is less than 3 but on the condition that the donor and receiver should have same region (and many other conditions)

Expected output is

```
emp.op <- data.frame(
  emp_id = c(1:32), 
  dealer_code = c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A3","A8","A4","A6","A6","A7","A1","A8","A9","A1","A2","A7","A8","A1","A1","A2","A2","A5","A4","A4","A10","A10","A10","A10","A3","A3","A11"),
  region = c("UK","US","OZ","IN","US","OZ","UK","IN","PAK","PAK","IN","UK","UK","OZ","UK","US","IN","UK","UK","UK","US","US","US","IN","IN","PAK","PAK","PAK","PAK","OZ","OZ","UK"),
  changed_code =c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A3","A8","A4","A6","A6","A7","A1","A8","A9","A1","A2","A7","A8","A11","A11","A2","A5","A5","A4","A7","A10","A6","A10","A10","A3","A9","A11"))
```

Here the changed_code column has shifted dealer codes and overall the count is uniform based on same region

```
df_2 <- emp.op %>%
  group_by(changed_code) %>%
  count()
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: I still don't understand your goal, and your description hasn't cleared it up. Can you please show the expected output for your sample input so I can check my understanding?

Comment: averaging out the number of dealers based on same region(filter condition)